# Use of "sudo" has broken my Cordova

Tags: macos, cordova, ionic-framework

Someone made the mistake of using "sudo ionic add platform ios" and it has entirely broken my cordova for x-Code.

Nothing will build in x-code due to permission problems about accessing Cordova.

If I run "ionic platform add ios", it gives me:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/mac1/.config/configstore/update-notifier-cordova.json'
You don't have access to this file.
```

During the build, it gives me a build failed message:

```
"   CompileC build/stashd.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/stashd.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyMainViewController.o stashd/Plugins/com.telerik.plugins.wkwebview/MyMainViewController.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/mac1/Dev/John/ionic5/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,stashd.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,stashd,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/mac1/Dev/John/ionic5/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/mac1/Dev/John/ionic5/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch"
```

Trying to run in x-code it tells me

```
You don’t have permission to save the file “project.xcworkspace” in the folder “stashd.xcodeproj”.
```

Again- all this started to happen when Sudo was used (I never had to use it before, and ionic/Cordova worked perfectly).

So far I've:

Removed & re-installed Node.js, Ionic, NPM and Cordova. None have helped- I still require sudo.

Comment: Did you try using `ionic add platform ios` for current user?

Comment: It's not a problem of node, cordova, it is a problem of your project. Try to remove and add again the platform. If this does not work, create a new project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First remove ios platform use `sudo`:

```
sudo ionic platform rm ios
```

or:

```
sudo rm -rf platforms
```

And then, delete files that can't be visited:

```
sudo rm ~/.config/configstore/update-notifier-cordova.json
```

And then, add ios platform without `sudo`:

```
ionic platform add ios
```

Hope this will help, regards.

Comment: Glad it could help you!